# Function to create diamond shape given a value

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm having trouble trying to create a diamond shape without manipulating html css or centering(It will be smart enough to add spaces). Been spending few hours trying out but still no success. Is this an impossible task without manipulating html or css? Any help would appreciated. Thanks.

[image: The current state]

Below are the functions for code:

```
function slope(val){

    document.write('function slope('+val+')<br>');
    doubleit = val*2;

    for(i=0; i<doubleit; i++){
        if (i < val){
            for(j=0; j<i; j++){
                document.write('*');
            }
        }
        if (i >= val){
            for(j=doubleit; j>i; j--){
                document.write('*');
            }
        }

    document.write('<br>');
    }
}

function diamond(val){

    doubleit = val*2;
    document.write('<center>');
    document.write('function diamond('+val+')<br>');
    for(i=0; i<doubleit; i++){
        if (i < val){
            for(j=0; j<i; j++){
                document.write('*');
            }
        }
        if (i >= val){
            for(j=doubleit; j>i; j--){
                document.write('*');
            }
        }

        document.write('<br>');
    }

    document.write('</center>');
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to understand what you're after... is the current output what you want it to be, but you want to remove the `<center>` tag (and have it still look the same)?

Comment: I don't see how you could create that indenting using nothing but space characters unless you have a font where a space is exactly half the width of an asterisk. (Because otherwise how could you space it to centre `**` under `*`?)

Comment: Why is this tagged with Java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get rid of the `<center>` tag, you'll have to:

- use a fixed-width font
- do the correct left justification
- insert spaces between the '*' characters

Example:

```
  *
 * *
* * *
 * *
  *
```

You can think of it as the ASCII version of the [Nine-Ball starting position](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rack_(billiards)#/media/File:9ball.jpg).

Let's give it a try:

```js
function diamond(val){
  var y, w, shape = '';

  for(y = 0; y < val * 2 - 1; y++) {
    w = y < val ? y : val * 2 - y - 2;
    shape += Array(val - w).join(' ') + Array(w + 1).join('* ') + '*\n';
  }
  document.write('<pre>' + shape + '</pre>');
}

diamond(7);
```

Comment: Yes this works.
I dont quite get this though..
w = y < val ? y : val * 2 - y - 2;

Comment: What I'm using here is the [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator). This code is equivalent to `if(y < val) { w = y; } else { w = val * 2 - y - 2; }`, where 'w' is the 'width' of the current row (number of '*' characters, minus 1).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

```js
function diamondOfWidth(n){
    var i, diamonds = '*';
    for(i=1; i< 2*n; i++){
        document.write('<pre>' + diamonds + '</pre>');
        diamonds += i<n? "  *": '';
        diamonds = i>=n? diamonds.slice(3): diamonds;
    };
    document.body.style.textAlign = 'center';
    document.body.style.lineHeight = 0.5;
};

function diamondOfHeight(n){
    var i, diamonds = '*';
    for(i=1; i <= n+1; i++){
        document.write('<pre>' + diamonds + '</pre>');
        diamonds += i< n/2? ' * *': '';
        diamonds = i>n/2? diamonds.slice(4): diamonds;
    };
    document.body.style.textAlign = 'center';
    document.body.style.lineHeight = 0.1;
};

diamondOfHeight(7);
diamondOfHeight(6);
diamondOfHeight(5);
diamondOfHeight(4);
diamondOfHeight(3);

diamondOfWidth(7);
diamondOfWidth(6);
diamondOfWidth(5);
diamondOfWidth(4);
diamondOfWidth(3);
```

```html
<h1> Diamonds </h1>
```

Comment: You should add more details to your answer. Detailed answers are useful for the original poster and other Stack Overflow users.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(i=1;i<=5;i++){
  txt = "";
  for(j=i;j<10;j++){
    txt += " ";
  }
  for(k=0;k<(i*2)-1;k++){
    txt += "*";
  }
  console.log(txt);
}
var txt = "";
for(i=5-1;i>=1;i--){
  txt = "";
  for(j=i;j<10;j++){
    txt += " ";
  }
  for(k=0;k<(i*2)-1;k++){
    txt += "*";
  }
  console.log(txt);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. This doesn't seem to be correct. The question is about placing the shape in html.

Comment: You should add more details to your answer. Detailed answers are useful for the original poster and other Stack Overflow users.

Answer (score 0):

i did it this way.

```
var width = 11;  
var num = (width+1)/2;  
for (let i = num-1; i >-num; i--) {
    for (let j = num-Math.abs(i); j < num; j++) {
        stars+=' '
    }
    for (let j = 0; j < 2*(num-Math.abs(i))-1; j++) { //2*num-(2*Math.abs(i) +1) simplified to 2*(num-Math.abs(i))-1
        stars+="*";
    }
    stars+="\n";
}
console.log(stars);
```